# Set a maximum processing of items in a BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, blockingcollection

I have a blockingcollection of downloads and I would like to have a maximum number of concurrent download I can do, aka a maximum number of concurrent await downloadService.download(release), but the number of items the BlockingCollection should be basically infinite, so let's say I can have 49945 downloads in the BlockingCollection but I should download at the same time just 5 as maximum, whenever a download is finished, it will get another one, in order if possible. Here's my actual code:

```
BlockingCollection<Download> sendQueue = new BlockingCollection<Download>(new ConcurrentQueue<Download>());
while (true)
            {
                var release = sendQueue.Take();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async rlZ =>
                {
                    //do whatever you have to do
                    await downloadService.download(release);
                }, release);
            }
```

Comment: you need to keep the counter for 5 items once any thread finished need to reduce the count and add new items into the queue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: @mjwills Isn't that going to limit the amount of elements the BlockingCollection can have instead of the number of concurrent actions I want to do with the elements of the BlockingCollection?

Comment: The `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and the `BlockingCollection` are not the most suitable tools to use when you have I/O-bound work to do, like downloading stuff from the web. You can see better ways to do it here: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations/)

Answer (score 1):

> Set a maximum processing of items in a BlockingCollection

You can't set this in a `BlockingCollection` because a `BlockingCollection` doesn't do any processing - it's just a collection.

If you want to restrict the number of simultaneous processors, then you'll need to put that in the processing code itself. The standard way of throttling asynchronous code is with `SemaphoreSlim`.

However, in your case, I'd recommend having `n` consumers. This makes the code cleaner.

```
var consumers = new Task[]
{
  Task.Run(ConsumerAsync),
  Task.Run(ConsumerAsync),
  Task.Run(ConsumerAsync),
  Task.Run(ConsumerAsync),
  Task.Run(ConsumerAsync),
};
await Task.WhenAll(consumers);

static async Task ConsumerAsync()
{
  foreach (var release in sendQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    await downloadService.download(release);
}
```

Tip: If you use an async-compatible queue like a `Channel` instead of a `BlockingCollection`, then you can use an async enumerable instead of a consuming enumerable and remove the `Task.Run` calls.

Comment: I have read about Channel and it's pretty awesome! I'm in a position where I have a single producer adding an unlimited and infinite numbers of Download to a queue (Channel right now) and n consumers (5 maximum concurrently), I'm currently really confused with it, do I have to create a single Task (Consumer) with a while true loop where I TryRead each Download item? Create n number of Task controlling that I have 5 and no more with SemaphoreSlim and WaitToReadAsync the Channel? As simple as it sounds, I just want to process an unlimited number of Web Downloads but 5 at the same time at max.

Comment: @TePi: For Channels, use a similar structure to the code I posted. Just replace `GetConsumingEnumerable` with `ReadAllAsync` and change the `foreach` to `await foreach`. Then remove the `Task.Run` calls. You'll end up with five asynchronous consumers.